# finding and openging a file with specific extension in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fopen

Is there a way to open the file with a specific extension in MATLAB?

If there is only one file that has the extension '.aaa' in the folder, and I would like to open the file using 'fopen' regardless of the actual filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dir function:

```
files = dir('*.aaa');
files(1).name
```